# Pars json file in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, deserialization

i have a .json file that i want to pars it and show items in page.
i created 3 class called :
bultan_details
bultan_new
bultan_tele
and this codes for parsing it :

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filePath))
                    {
                        var json = r.ReadToEnd();
                        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bultan>(json);

                        //var bultanDetails = result.Bultan_Details;
                        var news = result.BultanNews;
                        var telegram = result.BultanTelegram;
                        //Response.Write(bultanDetails.bultan_title + "<br/>");
                        foreach (var item in news)
                        {
                            Response.Write(item.description + "<br/><br/><br/>");
                        }
                        foreach (var tl in telegram)
                        {
                            Response.Write(tl.text + "<br/><br/><br/><br/>");
                        }
                    }
```

this is my Bultan class

```
public class Bultan
    {
        public bultan_details Bultan_Details { get; set; }
        public List<Bultan_New> BultanNews { get; set; }
        public List<Bultan_Tele> BultanTelegram { get; set; }
    }
```

but i get this error after running project :

> (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error
>   either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or
>   change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a
>   collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be
>   deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added
>   to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array. Path
>   'bultan_details', line 1, position 19.

and this is my json file content :

```
{
    "bultan_details": [
        {
            "export_url": "http://localhost/api/public",
            "bultan_title": "عنوان اول",
            "bultan_title2": "عنوان دوم",
            "bultan_title3": "عنوان سوم",
            "bultan_title4": "عنوان چهارم",
            "bultan_logo": "logo.jpg",
            "full_date": "بهمن 25، 1395",
            "morning_azan": "05:30",
            "noon_azan": "12:19",
            "sunset_azan": "18:02",
            "sunset": "17:43",
            "sunrise": "06:55"
        }
    ],
    "bultan_news": [
        {
            "id": 83773354,
            "title": "زمان واریز عیدی بازنشستگان فعلا مشخص نیست",
            "uptitle": "",
            "description": "MyContent",
            "source_name": "ایران آنلاین",
            "time": "1395-11-19 09:43:38",
            "copy_count": 20,
            "base_source": "خبرگزاری فارس",
            "news_group": "اخبار سازمان",
            "news_subject": "تست میشود 2323",
            "news_subject2": "امیر,نظر",
            "news_maker": "تست 25",
            "news_orientation": "negative",
            "news_template": "note",
            "notes": "خوب بود",
            "tone": "pro",
            "tools": "quip",
            "labels": "جالب,قشنگ",
            "another_sources": "کلید فارس,بام فارس"
        },
        {
            "id": 83442478,
            "title": "سایت استانی خبرگزاری فارس اردبیل رونمایی شد",
            "uptitle": "",
            "description": "Description",
            "content": "MyContent",
            "source_name": "ارس تبار",
            "time": "1395-11-16 22:01:00",
            "copy_count": 0,
            "base_source": "ارس تبار",
            "news_group": "",
            "news_subject": "",
            "news_subject2": "",
            "news_maker": "",
            "news_orientation": "",
            "news_template": "",
            "notes": "",
            "tone": "",
            "tools": "",
            "labels": "",
            "another_sources": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 83443525,
            "title": "Title",
            "uptitle": "",
            "description": "Description",
            "content": "MyContent",
            "source_name": "خبرگزاری مهر",
            "time": "1395-11-16 22:15:00",
            "copy_count": 1,
            "base_source": "خبرگزاری مهر",
            "news_group": "",
            "news_subject": "",
            "news_subject2": "",
            "news_maker": "",
            "news_orientation": "",
            "news_template": "",
            "notes": "",
            "tone": "",
            "tools": "",
            "labels": "",
            "another_sources": "تابناک کهکیلویه"
        },
        {
            "id": 83443417,
            "title": "Title",
            "uptitle": "",
            "description": "Description",
            "content": "Content",
            "source_name": "خبرگزاری ایرنا",
            "time": "1395-11-16 22:14:43",
            "copy_count": 1,
            "base_source": "خبرگزاری ایرنا",
            "news_group": "",
            "news_subject": "",
            "news_subject2": "",
            "news_maker": "",
            "news_orientation": "",
            "news_template": "",
            "notes": "",
            "tone": "",
            "tools": "",
            "labels": "",
            "another_sources": "خبرگزاری ایرنا"
        }
],
    "bultan_telegram": [
        {
            "id": 3919776484,
            "link": "https://t.me/Besuye_zohour/4977",
            "source_name": "️ بسـوی ظــهور ",
            "text": "MyText",
            "time": "1395-11-19 08:58:37",
            "base_source": "️ بسـوی ظــهور ",
            "news_group": "",
            "news_subject": "",
            "news_subject2": "",
            "news_maker": "",
            "notes": "",
            "tone": "",
            "tools": "",
            "labels": "",
            "another_sources": "",
            "news_orientation": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 3919776370,
            "link": "https://t.me/onlyshear/37507",
            "source_name": "ســــــــراۍ شــ؏ــــــر",
            "text": "MyText",
            "time": "1395-11-19 08:58:37",
            "base_source": "ســــــــراۍ شــ؏ــــــر",
            "news_group": "",
            "news_subject": "",
            "news_subject2": "",
            "news_maker": "",
            "notes": "",
            "tone": "",
            "tools": "",
            "labels": "",
            "another_sources": "",
            "news_orientation": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Show to us your json

Comment: Added json content, sorry my mistake i forgot to add json content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `bultan_details` is the same array in `json` as `bultan_news` and `bultan_tele`, you have to define it as a collection in dto class too:

```
public class Bultan
{
    public List<bultan_details> Bultan_Details { get; set; }
    public List<Bultan_New> BultanNews { get; set; }
    public List<Bultan_Tele> BultanTelegram { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [jsonutils.com](http://jsonutils.com) to create the object class from a JSON file.

Then id use Newtonsoft.json which you can find in the NuGet Package Manager. And the code below works fine for me -

```
Bultan data = new Bultan();

var file = Path.Combine(@"FILE PATH");
if (File.Exists(file))
{
    data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bultan>(File.ReadAllText(file));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to create a new object serialize it and merge it with your input file. So you will see differences..